# django-admin.py and proper way to alter PYTHONPATH on Dotcloud?

Tags: python, django, pythonpath, dotcloud

I don't have a `manage.py` and use different settings for `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and `django-admin.py` to switch between development and production environments. This is suggested both by Django docs and pydanny in "2 Scoops of Django".

My project resides in `/home/dotcloud/current/bipolar`. My settings are in `/home/dotcloud/current/bipolar/bipolar/settings/dotcloud.py`, following Django 1.5 directory structure. `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODuLE` is set in `dotcloud.yml` to be `bipolar.settings.dotcloud`.

I'm having trouble getting things to run Dotcloud. When I just follow the example tutorial, I already have to add a `export PYTHONPATH=/home/dotcloud/current/(hellodjango|bipolar):$PYTHONPATH` to the `postinstall` script.

Things get really hairy when using the supervisor to launch celery. I'm trying to run the command `django-admin.py celery worker`. But no matter how I try to get my `PYTHONPATH` set to `/home/dotcloud/current/bipolar`, it's not picked up. I've tried both

```
command = "PYTHONPATH=/home/dotcloud/current/bipolar:$PYTHONPATH django-admin.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -E"
```

and

```
environment=PYTHONPATH="/home/dotcloud/current/bipolar"
```

in the supervisord.conf to no avail. I've tried moving things to a shell script, setting the path before running it... That works for `postinstall`, after all! And it does work when running it on the shell, but it doesn't work when the machine is deployed.

So any help is suggested!

edit: I have since tried multiple things. I've re-added a manage.py that both sets the correct `sys.path` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, to no avail. Finally, I've added a `python-worker` service which has achieved nothing apart from failing twice as much (supervisord.conf gets read on both services, huh?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [the docs](http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django-celery/) are wrong. One can't set `directory = $HOME/current/` in `supervisord.conf`. Replace it with `/home/dotcloud/current/` and you're good to go.

I still couldn't get `django-admin.py` to work; I'm assuming it gets called with a Python binary outside of the virtualenv. I find `manage.py` a bit hacky; is there a better way?

My working `supervisord.conf`:

```
[program:celery_beat]
directory = /home/dotcloud/current/bipolar/
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
command = /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python manage.py celery beat --loglevel=INFO

[program:celery_worker]
directory = /home/dotcloud/current/bipolar/
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_error.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
command = /home/dotcloud/env/bin/python manage.py celery worker -E --loglevel=INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not work but have you tried:

```
command = "cd /home/dotcloud/current/bipolar && django-admin.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -E"
```

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't mention that in the `supervisord.conf` I also set `directory = $HOME/current/bipolar/`. But I tried it now, and it gives me:

`2013-03-14 08:03:35,217 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'cd /home/dotcloud/current/bipolar && django-admin.py celery worker --loglevel=INFO -E'` The paths are right; executing the copy-pasted command in the console again leads to `ImportError: Could not import settings 'bipolar.settings.dotcloud'`. But when I drop into a python shell in that directory, I can import it just fine.